# Copyright on code from public source

Tags: copyright, united-kingdom, intellectual-property, software, open-source-software

Let's imagine consultancy A develops a code for client B that use some free available code from a website so it's a derivative work from the free code (MIT license). Can consultancy A re-use the same derivative work in for client C without copyright infringement due to client B?

Comment: "Freely available" doesn't necessarily mean "free to use", what license is granted with the "free code"?

Comment: MIT license, edited question

Answer (score 1):

The consultancy can definitely work on the basis of the MIT-licensed code.  However, if the contract between A and B specifies that B gets the copyrights for the developed software and A does not retain rights, then the modifications that A made for B may not be used for C.  If A retains copyright, then there's no problem.